# Java-gradle-plugin validatePlugins task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am testing `validatePlugins` task from core plugin **java-gradle-plugin** which seems to be doing nothing during build or if I run it directly.

I have a build script that defined plugins with a nonexisting plugin class.
Note `foo.bar.NonexistingPluginClass` this class is not in my source code.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("simplePlugin") {
            id = "foo.bar.validation-plugin-test"
            implementationClass = "foo.bar.NonexistingPluginClass"
        }
    }
}
```

Now official [Gradle page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#sec:gradle_plugin_dev_usage) says following validation is being done:

> The implementation-class property references a valid class file in the
> jar.

Still when I run the `build` task which also triggers `validatePlugins` one and there are no warnings reported, nothing. Also if I check `build/reports/plugin-development/validation-report.txt` the file is just blank.

Instead what I see is that :jar task that gets executed even before validatePlugins is being executed throws a message in the logs as shown below:

```
> Task :compileJava
> Task :pluginDescriptors
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes

> Task :jar
:jar: A valid plugin descriptor was found for foo.bar.validation-plugin-test.properties but the implementation class foo.bar.NonexistingPluginClass was not found in the jar.

> Task :assemble
>...
> Task :validatePlugins
> Task :check
> Task :build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

Am I missing some additional configuration so that I get the warning that the implementationClass is not actually referring to existing class from the `validatePlugins` task? Or I misinterpreted documentation? Is this a bug?

PS: Running with Gradle 7.2, Java 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task [`ValidatePlugins`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/devel/tasks/ValidatePlugins.html) does not check plugin metadata but perfoms static code analysis on the plugin classes:

> Validates plugins by checking property annotations on work items like tasks and artifact transforms. This task should be used in Gradle plugin projects for doing static analysis on the plugin classes.

The output you see during the build matches what is described in the documentation of [java-gradle-plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#sec:gradle_plugin_dev_usage). It reads

> [...] performs validation of plugin metadata during `jar` task execution.

And further

> Any failed validations will result in a warning message.